Can't load neo4j 4.1.0 dump file that was generated on Windows on my Mac
I am trying to load onto a mac a neo4j v4.1.0 database dump file created with neo4j-admin dumped from my working database on a windows machine. The dump file loads fine after I explort it and then I reload it in Windows. Both the database that I dumped from and that I am loading to run version 4.1.0. On my mac I open a terminal for my specific database. I located my neo4j-admin command and run the following command: ./neo4j-admin load --from=../import/my-db.dump --database=neo4j --force but I get the error: Not a valid Neo4j archive: ..import/my-db.dump. I checked the file type on my mac and it says Zstandard compressed data (v0.8+), Dictionary ID: None. I have also tried the neo4j-admin restore function. I originally exported the database on my Windows machine through neo4j-admin dump
I know the version of Neo4j is old and I would like to upgrade it, but my Windows machine is dying and crashes frequently. I would like to get the data moved to my mac first where I can upgrade it.
How do I load this dump file that was generated on a Windows machine on my Mac? Is this an issue with file format? Why will the file load on Windows but not on my Mac?
Neo4j Version: 4.1.0
OS: Windows 11 (export)
MacOs Sequoia 15.1
API: neo4j-admin
Steps to reproduce

On a windows machine, create a neo4j v4.1.0 database through Neo4J desktop.
Open a terminal for a neo4j v4.1.0 database
Run the following command: neo4j-admin dump --database=neo4j --to=/var/backups/neo4j-database.dump
Copy the dump file created to a mac.
Create a database v4.1.0 in neo4j desktop.
Open a terminal for the database
Move the dump file into the import directory
Run the command: ./bin/neo4j-admin load --from=../import/neo4j-database.dump --database=neo4j --force

You will get the error:
Not a valid Neo4j archive: ..import/neo4j-database.dump
